# НОД для вещественных чисел

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте! Передо мной стоит следующая задача: написать на C++ метод, вычисляющий НОД для 2 чисел типа int ИЛИ double(класс шаблонный).

Взял алгоритм Евклида с небольшими изменениями:

```
template <typename T>
    T rational<T>::nod(T a, T b) {

        if (a == b) {
            return a;
        }
        if (a > b) {
            T tmp = a;
            a = b;
            b = tmp;
        }
        return nod(a, b - a);
    }
```

Работает при:

```
rational<double> rat(5, 10);//рациональная дробь 5/10
rat.nod(5, 10);//вычисление НОД 5 и 10
```

И не работает при:

```
rational<double> rat(5.1, 10);//рациональная дробь 5/10
rat.nod(5.1, 10);//вычисление НОД 5.1 и 10
```

Вопрос: почему так происходит, и как это исправить, чтобы работало в обоих вариантах? Заранее спасибо за ответы!

Comment: Что такое "не работает"? А как это должно работать? Что такое НОД для вещественных чисел вообще? Чему в вашем понимании должен быть равен НОД(5.1, 10)? С этого надо начинать.

Comment: @AnT: Наибольший общий (целочисленный) делитель? Здесь, судя по всему, это 0.1.

Comment: А «не работает», судя по всему, потому, что 0.1 не представляется точно в типе данных `double`. В частности, проверка на равенство чисел типа `double` бессмысленно.

Comment: Судя по всему, вам нужны рациональные числа над кольцом целых, то есть, `rational<int>`.

Comment: Понятие НОД определено только на множестве целых чисел. Для double такого понятия не существует, соответственно нельзя вычислить то, чего нет... Посему при использовании double-аргументов первое, что нужно сделать - это привести их тип к целочисленному (при необходимости с округлением), получить целочисленный НОД и преобразовать обратно в double.